# set up WLAN on a Ubuntu desktop to connect with wireless device

Tags: wireless

I'm using a desktop computer with Ubuntu 12.04 OS. This PC is connected to internet and a local network which is also connected by a wifi router.

Can I use this PC to connect to other wireless devices (via the wifi router)??

This is a bit tricky since it's Ubuntu

Could anyone help me with some hints??

Comment: Let me see if I understand. (Your computer) --> connected --> To Wireless router(which is also connected to DSL/Cable Modem?) -->

Comment: that's what I mean. My desktop PC and the wireless router are in the same local network under a modem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES! If other computer/devices are connected to the router...Just install Samba a network homegroup sharing utility just like the one in Windows OS. After that you have to configure the software, router and the other devices.

Comment: I've finally worked out on my device - a mobile robot control wirelessly with a PC. The network is quite similar to what you've said

Answer (score 0):

http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/

How to Turn Your Ubuntu Laptop into a Wireless Access Point

Comment: I'm using a desktop PC, not a laptop